# Cannot import a class from the same folder in python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I have been trying all kinds of solutions from the site, but nothing seem to be working for me. My folder structure is:

```
python_tutorials
    linked_list
       __init__.py
       linked_list.py
       queue_using_linked_list.py
```

In my `linked_list.py`, I have a class called LinkedList. I am trying to inherit this class in my `queue_using_linked_list.py` class Queue. So in my `queue_using_linked_list.py`, I did:

```
from linked_list import linked_list

from linked_list.linked_list import LinkedList

from linked_list import LinkedList
```

All these gives me the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'linked_list'"

```
from .linked_list import LinkedList
```

Gives me the error "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package"

I also tried moving the linked_list.py into a new package under linked_list, but still getting one of these error. In the pycharm IDE, all these show no errors, but when I execute they all fail. What am I missing?

Comment: Try `from linked_list import LinkedList`.

Comment: @Axe319 I have tried that already and it gives me the same error - `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'linked_list'`

Comment: This shouldn't make a difference but have you tried running it from command line? Also, can you add that to your post as one of the things you tried? I just set myself up a similar folder structure and it ran with no errors.

Comment: @Axe319 I have added. But I am not sure what is missing that it is not working for me. I tried from the command line too and same error

Comment: Which Python version are you running?

Comment: @Learningisamess I tried in Python 3.8.2 from the command line and Python 3.7.6 from PyCharm IDE

Comment: Can you set up a few test files? Something like `test_it.py` and put an empty class `class Test: pass` inside it. Then in the same directory put another file named `test.py` with `from test_it import Test` in it and try to run `test.py`.

Comment: @Axe319 This test works fine. But I am not able to get the same result from the actual scenario. I think I will re-do the stuff from scratch and try it again.

Comment: If the test works, perhaps you could include some code with how your class is defined as well as the code from where you're calling your imports.

Comment: @Axe319 I re-factored the py files and the packages and used the test example. Now the thing is it works from the command line, but not from the IDE. If I use the import statement that the IDE accepts, it does not work.At least it works from the command line is good.

Comment: In that case, which file from where in your folder structure is pycharm running?

Comment: @Axe319 From my `python_tutorials` directory shown above in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two import lines are correct, but you have to start the Python interpreter from the python_tutorials directory, not from the linked_list directory.

If you then do `import linked_list.queue_using_linked_list` it will work as you intended.